# my linux mint service do nothings

Tags: node.js, service, linux-mint

i have a node server and i want make a service to lunch the server.
when i execute the service to start it, i hav'nt error the console said "ok" but when i look if the server is lunched with 'forever list' there are no server.
i executed the function do_start and do_stop in a shell script it's work.
and the case * work when i write whatever

see the service :

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Author tibo
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin
DESC="Manage the printer server"
PATHLOG=/home/apitic/sfprojects/start_server_log.txt
PATHCONFIG=/home/apitic/sfprojects/printerHtml/config.js
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

do_start()
{
    date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S)
    #excute le server dimpression
    if [ -f $PATHCONFIG ]; then
        echo "START : ${date} : je lance le server" >> $PATHLOG
        log_action_msg "START : ${date} : je lance le server"
        forever start /home/apitic/sfprojects/printerHtml/server.js
        return 0
    else
        echo "START : ${date} : NO CONFIG FILE" >> $PATHLOG
        return 1
    fi
}

do_stop()
{
    date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S)
    #excute le server dimpression
    if [ -f $PATHCONFIG ]; then
        echo "STOP : ${sdate} : jarrete le server" >> $PATHLOG
        log_action_msg "STOP : ${date} : je lance le server"
        forever stop /home/apitic/sfprojects/printerHtml/server.js
       return 0
    else
        echo "STOP : ${date} : NO CONFIG FILE" >> $PATHLOG
        return 1
    fi
}

case "$1" in
        start)   log_daemon_msg "Start server printer"
                 do_start
                 exit $?
                 ;;
        restart) log_daemon_msg "Stop server printer"
                 do_stop
                 log_daemon_msg "Start server printer"
                 do_start
                 exit $?
                 ;;
        stop)    log_daemon_msg "Stop server printer"
                 do_stop
                 exit $?
                 ;;
        *)       log_action_msg "Usage: /etc/init.d/udoo {start|restart|stop}"
                 exit 2
                 ;;
esac
```

so if you have a idea, i want it
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution.
the script is good. i didn't see the server running because the process was executed with the root user.

So when i execute the forever list with my user, i saw just the node server executed by the user. I had to login with the root user to see the node server.